# Qt Creator Disassembler, what is he trying to tell me?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qt-creator

I have a bug somewhere in the program. I'm using Qt Creator. While debugging, it opens the Disassembler and the cursor goes to the following line:

```
0x77d50b2d  <+0x3948>        c6 05 85 82 d8 77 00           movb   $0x0,0x77d88285
```

How should I read this?

I guess Qt Creator is trying to help me but I cannot undertand how to use that information.

How should I use that information?

Comment: That's like assembly language hombre.  You're trying to move $0x0 to 0x77d88285 and there is a problem.  My guess is that you haven't initialized something properly or are passing a null reference somewhere

Comment: Google tells me you might be having qt4/5 version problems.  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=217657

Comment: Has the program crashed, or will it continue running without issue? If a crash has occurred, showing the reason for the crash and call stack with symbols would be helpful.

Comment: @Chemistpp, and what about `0x77d50b2d  <+0x3948>        c6 05 85 82 d8 77 00`, where should I go with these?